# How to convert a document with LaTeX content into a MS Word document?

Tags: conversion

I work with a publishing company and we are working on a book containing large amounts of scientific and/or mathematical charts, equations, etc. created with LaTeX. We do not have electronic versions of some of the chapters in the book.

Therefore, I have to scan the hardcopy and edit it on a computer. After scanning I'm given the option to save the document as a `PDF`, `JPEG` or `Editable Text (OCR`). I usually save it as a `PDF` or `Editable Text (OCR)`. However, when I do this and open the document in Microsoft Word the images, formulas, and any text corresponding to the images becomes grossly distorted and skewed in every direction. I have no working knowledge about using LaTeX or LaTeX documents. Does anyone know how I can rectify this problem? Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that this is not really related to LaTeX. I think also it is too complicated for any software to do much more than OCR a document, and even this produces quite a lot of errors, even with the best software.

Comment: There's no easy or automatic way to extract maths or images from scanned text.  The best you can hope for is to get most of the text.  And then scan the equations and graphics separately perhaps?  You could then include them as images in your output.

Comment: Also, have a look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15552/89976). I've used scantailor with good results before, but it won't help you with the equations. But you could do them manually.

Comment: This is really off-topic. Even if you had electronic versions, it would be off-topic unless you had the source code. If all you had was PDF (or DVI), the fact that LaTeX produced it would be irrelevant.