# Converting printed text to LaTeX

Tags: conversion

I wrote a science fiction novel back in 1990 or thereabouts. It was read by Del Rey twice, but was ultimately rejected. That was long before the days of self publishing. I still have a copy of the printed manuscript (111275 words).

I would like to try again. I need to scan the printed pages and convert to Latex. That way I can make changes and create a PDF. I couldn't make the tags thing work, but they would be "scan convert text Latex"

Comment: More or less the same question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15541/from-old-paper-documents-to-modern-latex-versions. I don't think the answer is immediately applicable but maybe it will give you some ideas.

Comment: And if you use Windows then you could try [InftyReader](http://www.inftyreader.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I despise all things Microsoft with a white-hot passion, and wouldn't use them even at gunpoint. I should have mentioned that I use a Mac. But I will check out the other question.

Comment: If you have your book as plain ascii/utf8 text, there is not much to do to get a first PDF. Use empty lines to separate paragraphs, mark section headings by `\chapter{...}`, `\section{...}`, `\subsection{...}` etc, add `\documentclass{report}\begin{document}` at the beginning and `\end{document}` at the end. This should compile and serve as a starting point for further improvements.

Comment: you could use any OCR reader to get the text from a scsan, google docs works OK and is free. Then addng the markup to latex for a novel should be pretty simple.